# Getting .focus() to work in jQuery 1.4.2?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to validate an input field when it loses focus and re-focus the field if the validation fails. But I cannot seem to get the field to re-focus. I have written a test case at http://jsbin.com/ahepo/edit . It is failing in Firefox 3.6.2 and IE 8, but working in Chrome 4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I'd come up with is:

```
$('#field1').focusout(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.val('not valid!');
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    $this.focus();
  },1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the call to `.focus()` in a timeout handler.  That way, it happens *after* the "focusout" completes.

```
setTimeout(function() { $this.focus(); }, 1);
```